# Connection refused error in Horizon

Tags: horizon, docker, postgres

Launching Horizon with `stellar/quickstart` docker image:

`horizon db init --db-url postgres://stellar:123456789@127.0.0.1:5432/core --stellar-core-db-url postgres://stellar:123456789@127.0.0.1:5432/core_stellar --stellar-core-url http://localhost:11626`

My `horizon.env`:

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://stellar:123456789@127.0.0.1:5432/core"
export STELLAR_CORE_DATABASE_URL="postgres://stellar:123456789@127.0.0.1:5432/core_stellar"
export STELLAR_CORE_URL="http://localhost:11626"
export LOG_LEVEL="info"
export INGEST="true"
export INGEST_FAILED_TRANSACTIONS="true"
export PER_HOUR_RATE_LIMIT="72000"
export NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="XLMNETWORK"
export DISABLE_ASSET_STATS="true"
```

Error:

`2019/10/29 13:30:50 connect failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Postgres server is either not installed or mis-configured. Can you connect to it from the command line?

You need to configure it to allow local connections. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html for more info.